# How do i generate different new objects with random attributes every time i run a function?

Tags: python, list, oop

I am making a project where you can manage the passengers on a buss. I have created the class system, and know how to generate the random attributes. But I don't know how to generate multiple new persons, with different attributes, when you choose to pick up a new person. I don't know how to make it so all of them doesn't save in the same variable and overwrite eachother when a new person is picked up, and given random attributes. I've been trying to utilize lists, but I'm not getting that to work either.

I also don't know how i would be able to manage every person using their name, since it will only be an attribute.

```
import random as rand

nameList = ["Jack", "Erik", "Bob", "Anna", "Leo", "Nikodemus", "Samuel",
            "David", "Lucas", "Marcus", "Noah", "Simon", "Harley", "Abigale" 
            "Magdalena", "Marie", "Lewis", "John", "Gus", "Robin", "Jakob"]


"""
Something similar to this to make it random
self.namn(rand.choice(nameList))
self.age(rand.randint(1, 120))
"""

class Person():
    """ 
    Person is a class for representing the persons in the bus. Each object that
    is created from the class has a name and a age, as well as methods to return
alternativly modify resepective attribute.
    """ 
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.namne = namne
        self.age = age 

    # Stringrepresentation of object.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"This is {self.namn}. He/she is {self.ålder} years old."


    # Setters
    def setNaem(self, newName):
        self.name = newName 


    def setAge(self, newAge):
        self.age = newAge


    # Getters
    def getNaem(self):
        return self.name


    def getAge(self):
        return self.age


# Adds a new person to the bus.
def pickUp():
    amountUp = input("How many passengers do you want to pick up?" "\n-> ")
    something.append(amountUp)
    print(f"Picked up {amountUp} persons.")
```

Comment: "I also don't know how i would be able to manage every person using their name," - if you randomly choose names from a list, that may be identical, so it's not a good way to identify the people.

Comment: There is no place in this code where you create even a single person. That would be the first thing to do, then add them to a list. Note also that we *don't* use setters and getters in Python. If you are following some tutorial, well, find another one. If this comes from some teacher, well, good luck, but know that he doesn't write Python code the way it's supposed to be written...

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are trying to do? create several unique Person objects to include in a list:

```py
import random


class Person:
    """ Person is a class for representing the persons in the bus. Each object that is created from the
     class has a name and a age, as well as methods to return alternativly modify resepective attribute."""

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    # Stringrepresentation of object.
    def __str__(self):
        return f"This is {self.name}. He/she is {self.age} years old."

    # Setters
    def setName(self, newName):
        self.name = newName 

    def setAge(self, newAge):
        self.age = newAge

    # Getters
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getAge(self):
        return self.age


# Adds a new person to the bus.
def pickUp():
    nameList = ["Jack", "Erik", "Bob", "Anna", "Leo", "Nikodemus", "Samuel", "David", "Lucas", "Marcus", "Noah",
                "Simon",
                "Harley", "Abigale", "Magdalena", "Marie", "Lewis", "John", "Gus", "Robin", "Jakob"]

    amountUp = int(input("How many passengers do you want to pick up?" "\n-> "))
    bus = []
    for counter in range(amountUp):
        name = random.choice(nameList)
        nameList.remove(name)
        age = random.randint(1, 120)
        person = Person(name, age)
        bus.append(person)

    print(f"Picked up {amountUp} persons.")
    pass

pickUp()
```

Then you can check what is inside the `bus` variable.